# Is there a way to see blunders, mistakes, missed checkmates in Stockfish

Tags: chess, uci, fen

I'm using [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/) and when I analyze a game, stockfish only shows best moves and value of position.
Is it possible to display blunders, mistakes and possible checkmates ?

For example, I have this [pgn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) position

```
1. e4 c5 2. Bc4 Nc6 3. Nf3 e6 4. O-O d5 5. exd5 exd5 6. Re1+ Nge7 7. Bxd5 Qxd5
8. Nc3 Qd8 9. Ne4 b6 10. d4 cxd4 11. Bf4
```

[image]

Stockfish calculation result

```
...
info depth 36 
seldepth 53 multipv 1 
score cp -623 
nodes 1018378783 
nps 3645086
hashfull 999 
tbhits 0 
time 279384 
pv c8e6 e4d6 d8d6 f4d6 e8c8 d6g3 h7h5 a2a4 a7a5 e1e6 f7e6 f3g5 h5h4 g3f4 e7d5 g5f7 f8e7 d1g4 d5f4 g4f4 h8f8 f4e4 c8c7 f7d8 f8d8 e4e6 e7f6 e6e4 c6b4 a1d1 d8d7 e4f4 c7b7 c2c3 b4c6 c3d4 d7d5 f4f3 d5d4 d1d4 f6d4 f3g4 b7c7 g4h4 d4b2
info depth 37 currmove c8e6 currmovenumber 1 
...
```

Stockfish shows that the  strogest move is bishop `c8e6` .

**What I want to achive ?**

Now I want to highlight the possible strongest moves and blunders.
For example, `g7` pawn will be highlighted as mistake (if user play`g7 - g6` or `g7 - g5`)  because of `Nf6` mate

[image]

Comment: Probably you will get a better answer here https://chess.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since chess engines are programmed to find the best lines I would say that this isn't possible (but I have no clue really). The engines uses lots of prunings that removes lots of lines that it finds bad and therefore most blunders should be pruned away at an early stage of their calculations. But I really don't know, I haven't seen anything like this before. Would be a cool feature though :)